# How to type object prop with union

Tags: typescript

How to type object props with union. I try with:

```
export type ThemeTypeDto = 'warm' | 'ocean';
export type ThemeDto = Record<ThemeTypeDto, { primary: string; secondary: string }>;
```

or:

```
export type ThemeDto = { [key in  ThemeTypeDto]: { primary: string; secondary: string } };
```

To restrain the object props to `'warm' | 'ocean'` but if I define a theme like:

```
const theme: ThemeDto = { warm: { primary: '', secondary: '' } }
```

or:

```
const theme: ThemeDto ={ ocean: { primary: '', secondary: '' } }
```

I've got:

```
Property 'ocean' is missing in type
```

or:

```
Property 'warn' is missing in type
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You only want one of the properties ?

Comment: I updated my answer with further information about why this behaviour happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you give `Record` a key type, when it resolves to an enum, or a string litteral union, it will require all of the possibilities to be defined. Unlike `Record<string, any>`, `string` being a "large" type it won't be able to narrow to a list of possibilities, that's why Typescript can't complain. But in this case, the options are finite, so you'll need to inform that not all properties are required.

You could either tell the `Record` is Partial, or define your mapped type with possibly undefined properties:

```ts
// Partial record, makes all properties optional
export type ThemeDto = Partial<Record<ThemeTypeDto, { primary: string; secondary: string }>>;
```

```ts
export type ThemeDto = {
  // Mapped types, add optional marker on your properties
  [key in ThemeTypeDto]?: {
    primary: string;
    secondary: string;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with interfaces instead of unions and by telling TypeScript that either ocean or warm can be undefined.

```
interface Theme {
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
}

interface ThemeTypeDto {
  warm?: Theme 
  ocean?: Theme
}

const themeWarm: ThemeTypeDto = { warm: { primary: '#ffff', secondary: '' } }
const themeOcean: ThemeTypeDto = { ocean: { primary: '#aaaaa', secondary: '' } }
```